# Class has no initializers Swift 4 iOS

Tags: swift

I implementing protocol in my swift class. But the error class has no initializer occurs.

```
protocol WebServiceResponseDelegate{
    func didRecieveResponseData(obj:Data)
}
```

`[image]

Comment: do not post code as image file.

Comment: oh okay but what is the solution of this?

Comment: Make your webDelegate object as optional

Comment: let webDelegate:WebServiceResponseDelegate? not !

Comment: i am using as optional but same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not create a strong reference to a delegate, because it will create a retain cycle. You should declare it as:

```
weak var webDelegate: WebServiceResponseDelegate?
```

With this you will solve the problem of the initializer too. If you say that a variable has value you need to give a default value or assign it through the initializer, But I assume you want to set it from outside 
like:

```
alamofireRequest.delegate = self
```

not through the initializer.

```
init(webDelegate: WebServiceResponseDelegate) {
 self.webDelegate = webDelegate
}
```

Also you have to specify that your protocol is a class to apply the weak reference:

```
protocol WebServiceResponseDelegate: class {
    func didRecieveResponseData(obj:Data)
}
```

To use the delegate you can not use a static func because an static func does not need to get initialized you can use: `AlamofireRequest.HitGetRequest(...).` Which is the value of the delegate there?, always nil.

> You need to use and instance method, (removing the static) and in the
>   classes that you are going to use it initialize the class.
>
> These kinds of methods are called type methods. You indicate type
>   methods by writing the static keyword before the method’s func
>   keyword. [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Methods.html)

You can not call variables from an instance when there is no instance.

```
let alamofireRequest = AlamofireRequest()
alamofireRequest.delegate = self
alamofireRequest.hitGetRequest
```

(Also don't use upper case in the functions names)

Comment: this is a good suggestion, but it still wont work while the function is a static function

Comment: 'weak' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not 'WebServiceResponseDelegate'

Comment: protocol WebServiceResponseDelegate: class {
    func didRecieveResponseData(obj:Data)
}

Comment: @ShahbazAkram I have added it to the answer :), This will solve the problem about the initializer

Comment: but now i receive this error:Instance member 'webDelegate' cannot be used on type 'AlamofireRequest'

Comment: @ShahbazAkram this is because of the static func as Scriptable says. Static func can be called without initializing the class, you need to remove the static and initialize the class, I will add it in the answer too

Comment: this is working fine now thanks a lot

Comment: @ShahbazAkram No problem :) Good luck ^^